# SECONDARY member of mongodb replica set is not match with PRIMARY

Tags: mongodb, replication, replicaset

I'm using a mongodb replica set with two nodes in different data centers.

One day, because of unknown packet drop, replica set was broken.

So I restored the replica set by removing/adding secondary node, but there is still something wrong.

Here is the status of the nodes, from the information given by rs.status() and rs.conf():

[image: rs.status() output]

[image: rs.conf() output]

Why last heart beat is too old?

Replication with two mongodb is not working

For example, the number of documents in the collection 'letter' is not the same across the two nodes:

[image: 9873 letter documents in one node]
[image: 9906 letter documents in the other node]

Comment: replica set with two members may fail anytime.. explain not working!

Comment: @NaeemShaikh Data in two mongodb is not match.

Comment: You might want to try at http://dba.stackexchange.com/ - this is more of a database system administration problem than a programming problem, so the expertise to answer your question might be found there.